# ANy website for uploading, reading PDF, doc files (more than 10GB)

Tags: pdf, documents, ebook

I have lot of eBooks collections on my hard drive, but that's on my home computer.
Every time I need eBooks I find on internet and then download it as sometimes I am too lazy to search the whole bunch of folders.

Is it possible to upload all PDF files on website where I can categorize them and then read it so that I can read from anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com)?

You get 1024 MB free, their 20 GB plan is only 5 USD per year. I assume by "more than 10GB" you meant more than 10GB of files, not single files that are over 10GB in size each. Those would be some monster PDFs if that's the case :)

Comment: Actually i thought about that before. I wanted to have separate account rather than gmail. Just in case some hacks in my account.

I have google app account , would love to associate docs with that but then i have no upgradation option.

But i think i can think of that. I have all comics as well in pdf format about 20Gb , i will upload those as well. I think 20$ for 80GB is not bad

Comment: I think i got an idea . I will make separate free google account and put all docs in there and then will share all the pdfs with main google account so that if someone hacks my normal account then i can withdraw the files any time.

Comment: That's actually an interesting idea. You've got quite a bit of uploading ahead of you though :)

Comment: Actually i thought a lot how to be hack proof. I have 5 gmail accounts which i am using since gmail came. 90% of time i use one main gmail address(main one). Then i realised that if someone hacks into it will be gone . So i made google app account(free) so that as i am domain owner i can reset the password any time if some hacks it. and  i am receiving all other 5 accounts mails using POP account. No one actually knows whether i have Gmaill APP email account as i reply from the same address to which email was sent from one place. I feel safe now